# Assistance on count if function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Name | subcounty |
| --- | --- |
| BULIISA TC | BULISA |
| BULIISA S/C | BUGANA |
| BULIISA S/C | KABOOLWA |
| BUTIABA T/C | BUTIABA |
| BIISO TC | BIISO |
| BUTIABA S/C | WALUKUBA |
| BUTIABA S/C | BUGOIGO |
| BUTIABA S/C | NYAMUKUTA |
| KIHUNGYA S/C | KIHUNGYA |
| NGWEDO S/C | NGWEDO |
| KIGWERA S/C | WANSEKO |
| BIISO S/C | Nil |

wanted to count data in column A that ends with "* s/c*" without counting similar twice.
expecting result as 6 having Buliisa s/c, Butiaba s/c, kihungya s/c Ngwendo s/c, Kigwera, Biiso s/c.

tried

```
=COUNTIF(UNIQUE('GREATER WEST'!C2:C13,FALSE,FALSE),"*s/c")
```

but getting no result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following formula, as is mentioned by @JvdV Sir

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A13,RIGHT(A2:A13,3)="S/C")))
```

---

Comment: thanks sir for the assistance. TC and S/C are in one cell combined. wat is disturbing is to count wit out repetition forexample those appearing twice. ie Buliisa S/C, Butiaba S/C.